# How do you select multiple items in ListView from code

Tags: c#, windows, listview, windows-8, selection

I am working with the new Windows 8 ListView-control. I have a list of users which are selected, depending on another list of users stored elsewhere.

Perhaps my situation is a bit specific, but my question is quite simple:
How do I select several items in a ListView-object from code?

Answer (score 0):

Yout list view has property called Items

```
 yourList.Items
```

This is a Collection of your items that are bind to the List. If you know indexes (or other uniq value) you can find them. If you have a list of indexes just take each from the list

```
 yourList.Items.ElementAt(index);
```

If you know an Id or Name of your item or other field you can make a loop where you`ll seek them in Items collection

Comment: Given I have something unique about each item in that list, how can I mark each of those elements as "selected"?

Comment: do you mean by clicking them on the list or to mark them as selected after some action that is made after list is loaded ?

Comment: My situation is like so - when I launch a view, a list is populated. When it is populated, I want all the items also found in another list (a subset of the same objects found in the ItemsSource) to be selected in the list. Or a bit more specific. I am displaying a list of all users registered in a system. In this specific view, you can choose a subset of those. I want to select those that were selected last time the view was shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .SelectedItems property.  Here is a simple example that fills a listview then marks the items at index 4 and higher:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (mylistview.Items != null) mylistview.Items.Add("Item at index "+i);
        }

        if (mylistview.Items != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= mylistview.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                if (i > 4)
                {
                    mylistview.SelectedItems.Add(mylistview.Items[i]);
                }
            }

        }
```